# Clang compiler; 'ld' ignores specified library search path

Tags: linker, clang

I'm trying to compile a program using `clang` with this command:

```
clang test.c -otest -L/var/sdk/usr/lib/
```

However, `ld` seems to ignore this completely and instead searches for library in the default directory, leaving this error:

```
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib for architecture armv7
```

Did I do something wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: You're just telling the compiler where to find the library it's linking to. You have to tell the OS where to find the library at runtime too! You can typically encode this information in the compiled binary itself — I don't know what OS you're using, but on gcc on Linux you'd do `-Wl,-rpath,/var/sdk/usr/lib`, and clang tends to have similar options to gcc, so it's worth a shot.

Comment: no luck, clang doesn't know what the -Wl or the -rpath option is. also, I'm using ios on arm-apple-darwin14 (iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have found the solution to my own question:

It was weird, somehow clang just doesn't like `-L` , but when I tried to using `-isysroot/var/sdk/` , clang finally decided to find the libraries (and headers) in the directory that I specified.

Hope this will help others with the same problem.